# lldb - passing hex value as an input while debugging

Tags: c++, c, security, reverse-engineering, lldb

I am learning lldb from security perspective. I am trying to perform a bufferoverflow in the below sample code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void return_input(void) {
char array[30];
gets(array);
printf("%s\n", array);
}

int main(){
return_input();
return 0
}
```

`gets` function is the target here.

While inside lldb console, I need to key in the long string that will override the `return` address. if I try a string like,
(lldb) AAAAAAA\x01\x02
They are being treated as individual characters and not hex values.

How do I pass **in hex values as input while inside LLDB session**? Basically, I am trying to overwrite the memory.

There are other answers where we pass the string as an argument, but i want to key in the data myself while inside the session.

Updating the lldb session.
[image]

In the below picture you can see that the hex are actually, converted into strings
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind to copy-n-paste your _minimal_ debug session, please? If you enter something on your terminal while `gets()` is active, you cannot enter characters by their hex values. You might need to prepare that in a capable editor and copy it.

Comment: updated with session pictures.

Comment: OK, now we see: It has nothing to do with lldb, as it is `gets()` that takes the input. The last `n` lets the program continue, it calls `gets()`, and that waits for you to enter something. After typing "enter", `gets()` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to enter arbitrary bytes via `gets()` into your variable `array` and beyond. This is not straight-forward and partially impossible, as the standard input stream and `gets()` commonly does not take all codes and filter some codes.

For example, if you want the byte 0x0D (or 0x0A, depending on your terminal) in your input, you could try to type <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But this key will get filtered by `gets()` as it thinks you have finished your input.

You can type many codes, by combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>Z</kbd> or umlauts or accented characters. But it is difficult to get exactly the sequence of codes you want.

You can try this: Prepare a sequence of characters that resemble your hex bytes in a text editor. Copy them into the console when `gets()` expects your input.

To see which character produces what code, consider to write a little experimental program that calls `gets()` and prints the received codes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[30];
    gets(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof line; ++i) {
        printf("%d: %X\n", i, line[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: Please adopt a code style and stick to it. Your source is not indented at all.*

Comment: Thanks. I understood your point. I did not paste the code from editor, Tried to type it in Stackoverflow editor :). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, hexadecimal just means how you represent something. By typing ascii characters you are already writing hex, just not the hex you want. If you type \x01 ascii you have actually typed 0x5C 0x78 0x31 0x32 ([courtesy of one of the first ascii tables I foun](https://geocachen.nl/geocaching/geocache-puzzels-oplossen/ascii-code/)d ).

You should do the inverse process. If you want to type 0x01 0x2 then you must enter a SOX and STX symbol.

Comment: Actually the codes are 0x5C 0x78 0x30 0x31, as the dump shows... -- Your answer would be helpful, if you suggest actual ways how to enter any bytes by the keyboard, as the OP asks for.